# Rails 3.1 and jQuery mobile: Best way to organize your JS & CSS while considering the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm integrating my Rails 3.1 app with jQuery mobile (Beta 2, at the moment), and I'm uncertain how to organize my JS & CSS.

I have this in my application.mobile.erb's head tag (copied right from http://jquerymobile.com/download/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>
```

Should I put my stylesheet_link_tag for 'application' right above this so my CSS styles don't override jQuery mobile's fancy CSS? What about the javascript_include_tag for 'application'?

Or maybe all of this should be entirely separate?

I'm just unsure how to organize all of this / if there is a conventional way to do this. Input appreciated.

(Please ask for more details if you need any.)

EDIT:
*I'm also wondering where to put my mobile-specific JS and CSS...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now a [jQuery Mobile Ruby gem](http://github.com/mjbellantoni/jquery-mobile-rails) that will make the jQuery Mobile files available to you in the assets pipeline.

Installation is easy. Simply add the gem to your apps `Gemfile`

```
gem "jquery-mobile-rails"
```

and run `bundle install`. Then, you can add

```
//= require jquery.mobile
```

to your `application.js` or wherever else you want to include the files.

Comment: This gem is similar and may also be of use. https://github.com/dbloete/jquery_mobile-rails

Comment: Thanks - I'll be sure to try this out when I get the chance.

Comment: The link is no longer vaild.

Answer (score 6):

Just like you, I was quite confused to figure out how to use jQuery Mobile (now final 1.0) with Rails 3.1's new asset pipeline.

First, drop jquery.mobile.js and jquery.mobile.css into assets/javascripts and assets/stylesheets respectively.

Second, insert "require jquery.mobile" into your application.js manifest

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.mobile
```

And the same to your application.css manifest:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= require jquery.mobile
```

Third, put "application.js" and "application.css" into the layout, application.html.erb

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Fourth, don't forget to add 'meta name~~~' line to make it work properly.

```
<meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
```

Also use the jQuery mobile properties properly, like 'data-role=”page”' in the page.
Others recommend to use gems like 'jquery-mobile-rails' or similar but I wouldn't.

Comment: This is straightforward and much less mysterious than using the jquery-mobile-rails gem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's really your decision on what you want to have precedence. Some things may have to have precedence over others just based on the order you call things (if a function is being called in file2, make sure file1 that defines that function is included before it).

In terms of how to work this in with asset_pipeline, you either download the assets yourself and bundle them in `application.css/application.js` or you keep it in `<head>` in the order that works for you.